# Extreme point of quadratic equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

For the below question read [here](http://cs61a.org/hw-sol/hw04/#q6):

> Write a function quadratic that returns the interval of all values $f(t)$ such that $t$ is in the argument interval $x$ and $f(t)$ is a quadratic function:
>
> $$f(t) = at^2 + bt + c$$
>   Make sure that your implementation returns the smallest such interval, one that does not suffer from the multiple references problem.
>
> Hint: the derivative $f'(t) = 2at + b$, and so the extreme point of the quadratic is $-\frac{b}{2a}$.

I would like to understand,

What is extreme point of quadratic equation? If I imagine a graph of that function>

why the extreme point of quadratic equation is $-\frac{b}{2a}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extreme point is a maximum or minimum, in the quadratic function case it will be global maximum of minimum.

If you know calculus, this is easy to understand: at the extreme point, the first derivative at that point is $0$. Differentiate $ax^2+bx+c$ you get $2ax+b=0$, thus $x = -\frac{b}{2a}$
[image]

If you don't know calculus, then this is the way you may understand: notice that quadratic function is symmetrical by its extreme. The quadratic formula tells you the two roots are $x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. They are symmetric by the extreme, so the extreme is at $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$.

Comment: derivate is 0 mean slope is zero. I am student of [gilbert_strang](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-005-highlights-of-calculus-spring-2010/) ): Derivate is used for continuos(varying slope) functions average is used for constant slope functions.avergae mean y2-y1/x2-x1

Answer (score 1):

Extreme point occurs where derivative vanishes. Setting derivative to zero 
$$ x_{ExtremePoint}= \dfrac{-b}{2 a}$$and corresponding 
$$ y_{ExtremePoint}= c-\frac{b^2}{4 a}$$.

Comment: Also, where $a\lt 0$ or $a\gt 0$, the extreme point is a maximum or minimum, respectively.